# How to join received multipart SMS ( GSM Modem )( C# )

Tags: c#, sms, gsm, at-command

I'm programming an app that receives Short Messages (**SMS**) from a **GSM Modem** (ZTE Corporation) (*+CMTI notifications*).

I've already done my program but when there is a *multi-part SMS* I can not connect them to each other, and all of them come in separate messages.(e.g a 3 part message comes in 3 different messages). how can I connect them and understand which one is after which one? (Consider Someone Sends me two 3-part messages one after another, How can I distinguish these two messages?)

- Programming language: C#
- SMS in Text Mode (AT+CMGF=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, by PDU Header I can find that if there is more smss and with user data header in that i can distinguish packets.

Answer (score 1):

// for gsmcomm users

```
List<string> messagesList = new List<messageList>();
List<SmsPdu> multiPartMsg = new List<SmsPdu>();


foreach (var i in modem.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Phone))
{
    string msg;

    if (SmartMessageDecoder.IsPartOfConcatMessage(((SmsDeliverPdu)i.Data)))
    {

        multiPartMsg.Add(i.Data);
        try
        {
            if (SmartMessageDecoder.AreAllConcatPartsPresent(multiPartMsg))
            {

                msg= SmartMessageDecoder.CombineConcatMessageText(multiPartMsg);
                messagesList.Add(msg);
                multiPartMsg.Clear();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}


    }
    else
    {
        msg = ((SmsDeliverPdu)i.Data).UserDataText;
        messagesList.Add(msg);

    }
}
```

Comment: I followed the following code snippet using Gsmcomm 1.21 version from Nuget. But I got random characters or garbage data string response from SmartMessageDecoder.CombineConcatMessageText(multiPartMsg);

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, as follow up to my response, here is the sample message i got

$eiSGYKAÅKÑKeCi§eARgAÜÑKAÜMAhQKADKgiABeiSGYKAneSiSÑOAh§§YAÜÑYSÑKABgARiAFCÑAdKoeSiKAjÑSckKAF§ÑiKÑiAL§eAr§keAnKEgSiKY¡DY§OAÜeAF§YYKOKY¡jÑSckKABeiSGYKgAFCÑARÑGeKCgKAr§keAnKEgSiKAdCÑWSÑOARÑAfKCeGQAJÑOSÑKgABÑIAFCÑANKiAZ§eKAheCMMSGAh§Ar§keAnKEgSiKÑΛkgiAfGe§YYADKY§oY¡BIIAhQKAVKso§eIAÜÑAhQKAh§aSGAr§kAnCÑiAh§ANKÑKdCiKABeiSGYKgABÑIAFYSGWANKÑKeCiKABeiSGYKgAh§ANKiALeKgQABeiSGYKgÑ@

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried **Nokia's Smart Messaging Concept**, for concatenating multi-part messages, but seemed many problems. So finally I found PDU header with some important things like...

If your message is multi-part you can check through

```
bool Is_Multi_PART = SmartMessageDecoder.IsPartOfConcatMessage(SMSPDU);
```

see here...

```
DecodedShortMessage[] messages = comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, storage);
            foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
            {
                GsmComm.PduConverter.SmsDeliverPdu SMSPDU;
                SMSPDU = (GsmComm.PduConverter.SmsDeliverPdu)message.Data;
                bool Is_Multi_PART = SmartMessageDecoder.IsPartOfConcatMessage(SMSPDU); 
                byte[] element1 = message.Data.UserData;
                if (element1[0] == 5)
                {
                    byte[] numArray = new byte[2];
                    numArray[0] = element1[3];
                    numArray[1] = element1[2];
                    int referenceNumber = BitConverter.ToUInt16(numArray, 0);
                    int totalMessages = element1[4];
                    int currentNumber = element1[5];
                }
            }
```

Also if your message is multi-part message it should always contain **PDU Header** with...

1. Reference Number.
2. Total Messages (Message/160).
3. Current Number of Message. (if you have 1 message with 250 length then its simultaneously 1,2).